# How to use output from make/compile/grep in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has its own built-in search functionality that is all good and fine. That's not what I'm asking about here.

I have a tool that spits out file locations in a format like `grep`'s:

```
path/to/file1.ext:34: found something
path/to/file2.ext:226: found something else
```

Some tools even add a second number, the column number. E.g. `ack` run with the `--column` option.

```
path/to/file1.ext:34:11: found something
path/to/file2.ext:226:16: found something else
```

Can I get such a list "into" eclipse, so I can click on the first line and it opens `path/to/file1.ext` on line 34, column 11?

I'm a heavy user of `ack`, `grep` and Perl one-liners, so I really miss that tool chain as an additional option when using Eclipse.

(I *do* know there are other good possibilities in Eclipse).

Comment: You can write an Eclipse plug-in that produces the grep output with links.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if a line printed to the ecilpse console looks like:

```
bla bla (File.java:34) bla bla
```

Then eclipse will turn it into a link and open `File.java` on line 34 when clicked. Perfect. It'll pick the first `File.java` in the classpath (which is fine for my purposes).

So I wrote a simple main() that opens a file containing output like I described (hard-coded for now to a file called `ack`), and uses a regexp to convert it to the above format and print it out when run. Not perfect, but 95% of what I was after.

```java
package my.package;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ShowAckGrep {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Current directory is: " + curDir);
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("ack");
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:.*/)?(\\w*?\\.java):(\\d+):\\s*(.*)");
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            // System.out.println("Line: " + line);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if (! m.matches()) {
                System.out.println("Ignoring: " + line);
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(
                "(" + m.group(1) + ":" + m.group(2) + ") " + m.group(3)
            );
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```